# require_once and include problems php

Tags: php

Somehow, I cannot include the file I want, neither using `require_once`, nor `include`. The file I want to include is in the same directory as the file in which I want to include it. I tried every combination, but still does not work.

The error I get trying to use `require_once`

> Warning: require_once(D:\PROJEKAT\wamp\www\Eif\db_connect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\PROJEKAT\wamp\www\Eif\create_user.php

I first tried with

```
require_once '/db_connect.php'
```

then I used

```
require_once '\db_connect.php' cause I realized that I have to use \ in windows
```

Then tried

```
require_once __DIR__ . '\db_connect.php'
```

And lastly

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Eif/db_connect.php';
```

I think that the path I'm using is good, but it keeps using it on the wrong way.

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR which is always correct on your platform

Comment: If it in the same directory, why not omit the slash at all?

Comment: @Dirkos ok, thanks, but what else can it be?

Comment: What PHP version do you use? `__DIR__` was first added in `5.3` (which *was* released in 2009, and stops support this month).

Comment: PHP doesn't care what directory seperator you use. Forward-slash should work on *nix as well as windows.

Comment: Try using the full path `require_once "FULL_PATH_OF_THE_FILE";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick answer

You should be able to do this:

```
require_once 'db_connect.php';
```

## Furthermore information

`require`, `require_once`, `include` and `include_once` are all the same with one exception: **require** will emit a fatal error on failure where as include will emit warning.

The other thing to bare in mind these actually search through the php ini `include_path` directive, so when you attempt to include another file php will search through those directories in order of the first directive.

By default this directive usually looks like: `.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear`.  This could be changed by a number of functions, even the `php.ini` which you would want to be aware of:

- [set_include_path](https://www.php.net/set_include_path) - Set the include paths directive;
- [get_include_path](https://www.php.net/get_include_path) - Show the current include paths;
- [getcwd](https://www.php.net/getcwd) - Show the current working directory;
- [chdir](https://www.php.net/getcwd) - Change the current working directory;

**NOTE** if using `set_include_path` you are not adding to the list, but overriding it's value; so it would be wise to know the correct way of setting this is:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPERATOR . '/path/to/new/location');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file you want to include are in the same directory this should work:

```
require_once 'db_connect.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

There has to be some mistake in the way you are trying to reach to the path.
You can use following php functions to debug it.

```
 <?php
   print_r(get_included_files()); // Write this above the file that you are trying to include     
  set_include_path('path_to_your_directory'); 
  // This will set the directory for once in<br /> your page after setting the path use require_once with the file name straight away
 ?>
```